# Is this good routing practice?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to develop an `Angular` frontend and unfortunally I am quite unexperienced as well.

I wrote this code to navigate between different components onto another component and I cant really judge if this is good practice.

Maybe you can help.

This is my `component.ts`

```
 activateCoredataComp() {
  this.coredataIsActive = true;
  this.careerIsActive = false;
  this.skillsIsActive = false;
  this.projectsIsActive = false;
}

activateCareerComp() {
    this.coredataIsActive = false;
    this.careerIsActive = true;
    this.skillsIsActive = false;
    this.projectsIsActive = false;
}

activateSkillsComp() {
    this.coredataIsActive = false;
    this.careerIsActive = false;
    this.skillsIsActive = true;
    this.projectsIsActive = false;
}

activateProjectsComp() {
    this.coredataIsActive = false;
    this.careerIsActive = false;
    this.skillsIsActive = false;
    this.projectsIsActive = true;
}
```

And this is my html

```
<jhi-coredata *ngIf="coredataIsActive"></jhi-coredata>
<jhi-career *ngIf="careerIsActive"></jhi-career>
<jhi-skills *ngIf="skillsIsActive"></jhi-skills>
<jhi-projects *ngIf="projectsIsActive"></jhi-projects>
```

Thank you in aticipation

Comment: If you only ever show one at a time, why not use `ngSwitch`? Also note you're *not* navigating there; you could actually use the router.

Comment: how many places in your code do you need to change if you add/remove one view?  I would say its spaghetti code. Use an enumeration + ngSwitch

Comment: Thanks a lot. ngSwitch seems viable. Ill try :)

Comment: if you are expecting more than one view to view at a time, dont go for switch

Comment: can you share where you are calling these functions?

Comment: WORKS! Feels like I made fire the first time. Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, I would rather use **query parameter**s in the routing and depend on them show the corresponding view.

In such case, you will just need to **redirect** the user to the current route with the parameter, and the amount of code in the component will be dramatically reduced.

```
activateProjectsComp() {
    this.router.navigate(['../'], {
        relativeTo: route,
        queryParams: {
            projectsIsActive = true;
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="list-inline">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs text-center list-centered">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" (click)="activateCoredataComp()"><span jhiTranslate="profiletool.profilesdashboard.editor.coredata"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" (click)="activateCareerComp()"><span jhiTranslate="profiletool.profilesdashboard.editor.career"></span> </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" (click)="activateSkillsComp()"><span jhiTranslate="profiletool.profilesdashboard.editor.skills"></span> </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" (click)="activateProjectsComp()"><span jhiTranslate="profiletool.profilesdashboard.editor.experience"></span> </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```